# Any Good Analytics Plugins for WordPress? (standalone)

Tags: plugin-recommendation, customization

Recommend any good analytics plugins you may have used and found useful. Reports such as site traffic by page, point of entry, top out going links, browser and OS information. The plugin may be paid or free.

**EDIT**: The reason I asked this question is to discover any new plugins that are not very popular but others have found useful. Please post any analytics plugin you may have found useful.

Comment: Under _standalone_ you mean self-hosted analytics or something else?

Comment: Yes, self-hosted. Not relying on Google analytics or anything. The data should be completely stored on the local server.

Answer (score 2):

Wordpress' analytics - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/stats/

Comment: As clarified in comment for question - doesn't fit self-hosted criteria.

Answer (score 0):

I've found [Open Web Analytics](http://www.openwebanalytics.com/) very useful.  They even have [a plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/owa/) which integrates very well with a wordpress install.  I'm not 100% sure, but I believe it is self hosted.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [wassup](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wassup/) for pretty in-depth analytics when I've needed them and google analytics hasn't been an option. Not the most user friendly, but it'll store every last bit of data that it can about a user, then you can filter through it (manually or otherwise)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Roguelytics: https://wordpress.org/plugins/roguelytics/

Recently released.